# How to add language trans tab to content

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

I want to make my site multilanguagal.
The first step is to add other language tabs when I create new content.
The second step is to add a language switcher in a some position in website.

I've read and seen some articles like [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Language_Switcher_Tutorial)

But this is not my goal.

How should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What **is** your goal then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are in right way...
After that, you will have to select the modules and content in which language you want to display each one. Look this menu option:

[image]

You can have elements in "language 1", others in "language 2", and other in "all languages".

I hope this helps.